# SPRESENSEを使った音声認識について

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEに特定の音声が入力された場合にアプリケーションを動作させるようなものを作りたいと思っております。
開発ガイド11.3. Audio Subsystemを見ると、11.3.2. レイヤ構造についてのObject Level SDK APIにRecognition Objectというものを見つけました。
これを使用すると音声認識ができるのでしょうか？
もしその場合、これを利用したサンプルプログラム等はございますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせの件についてお答えいたします。

現在のSpresense SDKでは、 *Recognition Object* は未対応になります。
今後のリリースで対応を予定しています。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム